# Is it possible to make Django urlpatterns from a string?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have a list of strings that is used to define navigation pane in a Django layout template. I want to use the same list for view function names and use a loop to define urlpatterns in urls.py accordingly.

Example:

```
menu = ["register", "login", "logout"]
urlpatterns = [path("", views.index, name="index"),]
```

From the above, I want to arrive at

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("/register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("/login", views.login, name="login"),
    path("/logout", views.logout, name="logout"),
]
```

I am able to pass the route as str and kwargs as a dict, but struggling with transforming the string into a name of a callable views function. Is this possible?

```
for i in menu:
    url = f'"/{i}"' #works when passed as parameter to path()
    rev = {"name": i} #works when passed as parameter to path()

    v = f"views.{i}" #this does not work
    v = include(f"views.{i}", namespace="myapp") #this does not work either
    
    urlpatterns.append(path(url, v, rev))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
menu = ['register', 'login', 'logout']
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    *[path(f'{name}/', getattr(views, name), name=name) for name in menu],
]
```